# UILocalNotification Sound Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have some problems with sound of UILocalNotification. I have the user permissions in app delegate.

It's my code:

```
var nottypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
var notsettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: nottypes, categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notsettings)
```

Code for notification:

```
var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Simple"
notification.alertTitle = "Back To App!"
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 20)
notification.soundName = "Chord"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always take a look at the documentation before posting a question at S.O. If you read the first line of the definition of [soundName's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName) property it says:

> For this property, specify the filename **(including extension)** of a sound resource in the app’s main bundle or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or badges an app icon, it plays this sound. The default value is nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.

So try:

```
notification.soundName = "Chord.mp3"   // use .mp3 or your file extension if it is not an mp3
```

Comment: Remember not to use the full file path including the path to the bundle itself.  I.e. don't use NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "caf")

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, I had to do the following steps:

1. Convert the file from mp3 or wav to caf.
   As stated in other answers you can convert wav, aif and mp3 files in terminal using the command:

   `afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 in.wav out.caf`
2. You can also export with Quicktime 7 as .aif with the following
   settings Linear PCM Rate 44.100 Linear PCM sample size 16 these aif
   files seem to be supported.
3. Make sure you files are less than 30 seconds, i.e 29 seconds or less.
4. Add you files to the root of your bundle, you can drag drop into Xcode or right click "add files to (projectname)"
   Note you must select the following options:
   a)Destination Copy items if needed
   b)Add to targets (your build name(s))
   4)Reference the file by its name including the extension e.g
   `localNotification.soundName = "Chord.caf";`

Make sure you delete the app from the device / simulator between tests or you will not see the results of your changes.

If your still having problems, check the sound file file is in the root of the project.
Check the Sound file "Target Membership" is selected in the show file inspector.